# How to customize CultureInfo's default calendar?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, calendar

I want to customize calendar to persian but after setting CultureInfo as this:

```
CultureInfo fa = new CultureInfo("fa-IR",true);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = fa;
```

[image: calendar]

name of month and days don't changed so decided to override default calendar.

How can I do that?

Comment: What is your application? Winforms, WPF, ASP.Net? What is this calendar control?

Comment: I use ASP.NET 4 with `asp:Calendar`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a subclass of `CultureInfo`. The property of it will not be read-only and you can assign to it..

Answer (score 7):

overriding for beginners like me:

```
public class PersianCulture : CultureInfo
{

    private readonly System.Globalization.Calendar cal;

    private readonly System.Globalization.Calendar[] optionals;

    public PersianCulture()

        : this("fa-IR", true)
    {

    }
    public PersianCulture(string cultureName, bool useUserOverride)

        : base(cultureName, useUserOverride)
    {
        cal = base.OptionalCalendars[0];
        var optionalCalendars = new List<System.Globalization.Calendar>();
        optionalCalendars.AddRange(base.OptionalCalendars);
        optionalCalendars.Insert(0, new PersianCalendar());
        Type formatType = typeof(DateTimeFormatInfo);
        Type calendarType = typeof(System.Globalization.Calendar);
        PropertyInfo idProperty = calendarType.GetProperty("ID", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        FieldInfo optionalCalendarfield = formatType.GetField("optionalCalendars",BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var newOptionalCalendarIDs = new Int32[optionalCalendars.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < newOptionalCalendarIDs.Length; i++)

            newOptionalCalendarIDs[i] = (Int32)idProperty.GetValue(optionalCalendars[i], null);
        optionalCalendarfield.SetValue(DateTimeFormat, newOptionalCalendarIDs);

        optionals = optionalCalendars.ToArray();

        cal = optionals[0];

        DateTimeFormat.Calendar = optionals[0];
        DateTimeFormat.MonthNames = new[] { "فروردین", "اردیبهشت", "خرداد", "تیر", "مرداد", "شهریور", "مهر", "آبان", "آذر", "دی", "بهمن", "اسفند", "" };

        DateTimeFormat.MonthGenitiveNames = new[] { "فروردین", "اردیبهشت", "خرداد", "تیر", "مرداد", "شهریور", "مهر", "آبان", "آذر", "دی", "بهمن", "اسفند", "" };

        DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames = new[] { "فروردین", "اردیبهشت", "خرداد", "تیر", "مرداد", "شهریور", "مهر", "آبان", "آذر", "دی", "بهمن", "اسفند", "" };

        DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames = new[] { "فروردین", "اردیبهشت", "خرداد", "تیر", "مرداد", "شهریور", "مهر", "آبان", "آذر", "دی", "بهمن", "اسفند", "" };

        DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedDayNames = new string[] { "ی", "د", "س", "چ", "پ", "ج", "ش" };

        DateTimeFormat.ShortestDayNames = new string[] { "ی", "د", "س", "چ", "پ", "ج", "ش" };

        DateTimeFormat.DayNames = new string[] { "یکشنبه", "دوشنبه", "ﺳﻪشنبه", "چهارشنبه", "پنجشنبه", "جمعه", "شنبه" };
        DateTimeFormat.AMDesignator = "ق.ظ";
        DateTimeFormat.PMDesignator = "ب.ظ";

    }
    public override System.Globalization.Calendar Calendar
    {

        get { return cal; }

    }
    public override System.Globalization.Calendar[] OptionalCalendars
    {

        get { return optionals; }

    }
}
```

then in `Page_Load`:

```
PersianCulture fa = new PersianCulture();

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = fa;
```

form [here](http://barnamenevis.org/showthread.php?281309-%D8%AA%D9%82%D9%88%DB%8C%D9%85-%D8%B4%D9%85%D8%B3%DB%8C-%28Persian-Calendar%29-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D9%88%DB%8C%DA%98%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%AF%DB%8C%D9%88-2010-%28vs-2010-visual-studio-2010%29)

Comment: Thank you. However, in >= .NET4.5, the class `System.Globalization.CultureTableRecord` can not be found in `typeof(DateTimeFormatInfo).Assembly`

Answer (score 2):

You can set CultureInfo of thread before the control is rendered and restore once the control is rendered.

Output :

[image]

Below example show's how you can render two different calendar with different CultureInfo.

Default.aspx

```
<%@Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Globalization" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Threading" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <% Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fa-IR");%>

        <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server">
        </asp:Calendar>
        <%
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        %>
        <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar2" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: is difference in use this code in `PageLoad` or where you said?

Comment: no, page load is all the same, i havent changed anything in it

Comment: this is arabic not persian and after I used your codes , again calendar as I shown in question appeared.

Comment: @majidgeek - sorry m8! cant be of more help! i do winform works, i am not familiar at all with WebForm