# Getting current Date by CultureInfo

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library, .net-core

I'd like to get localized date in my Xamarin Forms app. I have tried two ways that work just fine in ASP.NET MVC, but I wonder why neither of them works in Xamarin.

```
var currentDate DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/mm/dd", new CultureInfo("fa-IR"))
```

And by using culture info's calendar:

```
var month = new CultureInfo("fa-IR").Calendar.GetMonth(DateTime.Now);
```

Both of these methods gave me the current date in `en-US`.

Apparently, `PersianCalendar` is [supposed](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Globalization.PersianCalendar) to be there. I can't understand what I'm missing?

I even tried NodaTime by, `SystemClock.Instance.Now.InZone(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["‌​Asia/Tehran"]).Date.‌​ToString()` and the date is still in default culture!

**UPDATE**

Finally, [Persian Calendar Plus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PersianCalendarPlus/) did the job! But it would be very useful if someone could get the bottom of it!

Comment: If you run into limitations using DateTime, it may be helpful to know that there are other date/time libraries out there for .Net. Grandmaster Skeet's NodaTime is one but there are others.

Comment: @bubbleking, I'm using it [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27853841/3967440) and I still get `en-US` date by `SystemClock.Instance.Now.InZone(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Asia/Tehran"]).Date.ToString()`.

Answer (score 1):

.Net framework doesn’t support Persian calendar for the culture. This culture doesn’t accept the calendar; therefore display of DateTime in this culture is impossible.

You need to create a custom [helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15817348/how-to-customize-cultureinfos-default-calendar) or some [extension](https://persianculture.codeplex.com/) as mentioned here.

Using the above extension you can set like this,

```
// create an instance of culture
CultureInfo info = new CultureInfo(“fa-Ir”);
//set Persian calendar to it without get exception
info.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = new PersianCalendar();
```

Comment: `.Net` does support `fa-IR` culture and I'm using it in `MVC` apps, am I missing something?

Comment: @Akbari did you try as above?

Comment: it seems that `.Net core` doesn't have [Persian Calendar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar(v=vs.110).aspx) anymore!

Comment: @Akbari Thats what i have mentioned

Comment: That's awful, but thanks for your help. Would you please note in your answer that this is related to `.Net Core` to make it more complete,